# I am facing an issue in creating CSV File using stringbuilder csv in java

Tags: java, csv

I am creating a CSV file where i would **like to insert the data in cell like 4/4** (Example)

then in Excel file it was **showing** as **4-Apr instead of 4/4**

So I am asking you for the solution.

I **tried** with **Escape sequences not helped me**.

My code:
**builder.append(4 + "/" + 4 + ",");**

In 
generated file it was showing as 4-Apr

**Expected** : **4/4** in Excel sheet
Now **i am getting** output as : **4-Apr**

Comment: Where is your code? Can you show what you have tried so far?

Comment: How looks your "Example"?

Comment: @deHaar builder.append(4 + "/" + 4 + ","); my code to build one cell in a row in excel using java. Due to private issues i can post only the line of code where i am facing issue sorry for that

Comment: @reporter I wan to show data something like 4/4 in my excel that will be builded by java but after creating an excel it was showing it as 4-Apr (Date format)

Comment: Do you need to display your data as *X/Y* or would some substitute like *X of Y* be sufficient, too? Do you want to display a formula (division) or something like *two of four*, like unsuccessful logins or anything... *4 of 4* would definitely not be interpreted as a date by Excel.

Comment: @deHaar we are displaying X of Y only but now the requirement changed to X/Y

Answer (score 2):

Try opening the CSV with a texteditor.

Excel sometimes assumes, how to display a given cell. And in this case it guesses "date".

Try prepending a " before 4/4, it might work, but this will contaminate your data.

HTH!

Comment: I did the same but i shouldn't use the because my expected output should be like 4/4 only no other characters should be in that

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all your answers,

I found an answer for my Question
After many trails at one trail we got the answer.

builder.append(4+"\t/"+4+","); 
resolved my issue.

But not sure how it got resolved by trying this?
Can anyone help me